# Caffeine 3 - Deprecation of CacheWriter

Tags: spring-boot, caffeine-cache

I have a SpringBoot app with a customized Caffeine cache. Specifically, this cache implements `com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.CacheWriter` to do some post processing after an item is added or removed to the cache. However, the CacheWriter class was removed in Caffeine 3.X with the recommendation to

> Consider instead using Map compute methods for extending manual write
> and remove operations.

I have not found any examples on doing this properly. Has anyone managed to get it working successfully please?

Comment: The intent was to avoid some confusion and to be closer to how you would do the same work using a `ConcurrentHashMap` which is a compute method. Spring Cache that does make it less obvious as you have to program to their apis, where I suspect maybe Spring events would be their intended approach (but am not familiar).